# ProcessBuilder returning eclipse installation directory when triggered from servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, processbuilder, servlet-3.0

I used the ProcessBuilder to ch current directory from a standalone java class and it correctly showed me the relative project location. But when i triggered the same code from a servlet, it returned me the value of tmy eclipse installation directory

Can anybody help me out with this weird behavior of eclipse

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "chdir");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it....... It was just that I was running the above code in a Dynamic Web Project, which creates a copy of the project in the .metadata folder and ultimately runs that copy in runtime. That was the reason that on running the code in eclipse, I was getting a path of project copy location and not the original one.